# How to specify network interface for different protocols?

Tags: macos, network, smb, ftp

At work, I have 2 interfaces active: WiFi and Ethernet.

Eth connects to company network for shared volumes over SMB. But then no Internet.

WiFi connects to Internet, but not to company network.

I cannot mount shared volumes if "Set Service Order" has WiFi in first position; and I cannot access my FTP if it's set to Ethernet.

Is there some way I can specify which protocol will use which interface?

Or at least direct certain IPs/servers to Eth?

Comment: Are you doing this to avoid a company policy about connecting (or not connecting) to the Internet?  There can be good security reasons to implement such a policy. Just saying, be careful.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [this article](https://www.ursecta.com/2017/08/27/static-route-on-osx/), I did it with

```
sudo networksetup -setadditionalroutes Ethernet 10.25.254.66 255.255.255.0 10.25.19.254 10.25.252.223 255.255.255.0 10.25.19.254
```